# Separate stacked tables in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have an  excel file of stacked tables that in Pandas looks like:

```
d = {'col1': ['flow', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'handle', 'bs', 'cd', 'fg'],
'vals': [np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

in sum rows we have a defined field that is like a header of a small table (here **flow** and **handle**).

I wanted to separate headers and rows below them in separate dictionaries. My idea is to create an index column with the name of headers (flow and handle) and then use `pd.groupby()` to create `dict`. (Assuming I already know  `header_name = [flow, handle]`
what would be the best way to reach my goal and get a data framevlike:

```
idx = ['flow', 'flow', 'flow', 'flow', 'handle', 'handle', 'handle', 'handle']
df.index = idx
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do something like:

```
header_name = ['flow', 'handle']
df.index=df.col1[df.col1.isin(header_name)].reindex(df.index).ffill()
print(df.rename_axis(None))

          col1  vals
flow      flow   NaN
flow         A   1.0
flow         B   2.0
flow         C   NaN
handle  handle   NaN
handle      bs   4.0
handle      cd   NaN
handle      fg   6.0
```